# Gulp serve not working on mac

Tags: macos, networking, gulp

I used to have a linux and this project would run just fine. But after I switched to OSx, my gulp serve stopped working.

[image]

From the terminal everything seems to be normal

[image]

My gulpfile serve:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browsersync.init({
        proxy: "bookrosa.dev",
    port: 3001
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the task to

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browsersync.init({
    port: 3001,
    server: {
         baseDir: './'
    }
    });
});
```

worked fine.

Comment: Running into this issue with a local wordpress install. adding baseDir didn't help. Anyone got another fix?